# Getting Call to a member function getParam() on a non-object in zf2

Tags: zend-framework2

In my MCQ software, i am getting this error when i try to run test

'Getting Call to a member function getParam() on a non-object in Module/Application/Module.php on line 33.

Module.php

```
<?php
namespace Application;

use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
use Zend\Session\Config\SessionConfig;
use Zend\Session\Container;
use Zend\Session\SessionManager;

class Module
{

/*public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
        $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
        $viewModel = $e->getApplication()->getMvcEvent()->getViewModel();
        $viewModel->username = 'sdfsdfdf'; 

    }   
    */
     public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {   $this->initSession(array(
                            'remember_me_seconds' => 180,
                            'use_cookies' => true,
                            //'cookie_httponly' => true,
                            ));
        $sm = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
        $router = $sm->get('router');
        $request = $sm->get('request');
        $matchedRoute = $router->match($request);
        $params = $matchedRoute->getParams();
```

last line is line 33.

Can somebody suggest me why am getting this error?

Comment: $router->match will only return an object if the request can be routed, if it is invalid it will be NULL. Are you sure the route is valid?

Comment: How can i check that?. Actually it was working properly. Now it gives this error

Comment: Need more information to debug properly, maybe check the contents of $request first, look at requestUri, make sure its what you think it is.

Comment: What are you trying to get? Maybe I can make a suggestion on how to get the parameter you are interested in...

Comment: Actually, it is online test. Admin will generate the test, with time duration. When student takes his test, this error is getting displayed. It because of time frame. if i give more time for test then error will come after few mins. if i give less time error will come immediately.